# Converting .tex to .doc - LaTeX2RTF

Tags: packages, document-classes, msword, latex-to-word

As the title says, I've converted an academic paper that I have in TeX that needs to be converted into Word (damn you old-school publishers!). After trying a bunch of programs, I've had the best outcome with LaTeX2RTF. It has even rendered my external image files beautifully, however, the only thing it's lacking right now is the mathematical formulas.

By looking at this [image: the error screen], it seems that  LaTeX2RTF doesn't acknowledge the **llncs** class, even though *llncs.cls* is included in the same folder as the .tex file. Then it follows by flagging the included packages and my user-defined macros as unknown.

Is it simply the case that LaTeX2RTF can't parse class files and/or support some packages, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know what all the red blocks mean but the error seems fairly clear: you are using an unsupported class, unsupported packages and (so) unsupported commands. I don't know how this converter works as I've never used it, but arbitrary code will not, generally, convert properly. I've had the best luck with tex4ht, converting to ODT format and then exporting from LibreOffice to Word. But even though that is essentially parsing the code as code, you still have to be careful to keep things reasonably standard.